# spring-boot-maven-plugin and maven-dependency-plugin seems incompatible with buildpack for injecting dependency

Tags: spring-boot, maven, newrelic

Migrating from jib to spring-boot-maven-plugin It seems that the image is not able to find the new relic agent I am trying to install. Here is my pom.xml:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <image>
              <env>
                  <BP_JVM_VERSION>17</BP_JVM_VERSION>
              </env>
          </image>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

       <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>unpack-newrelic</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <includeGroupIds>com.newrelic.agent.java</includeGroupIds>
                  <includeArtifactIds>newrelic-java</includeArtifactIds>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Using dive I am able to find the path to the agent which is `-javaagent:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/newrelic-java-8.3.0.zip` but when the container is starting I am having the following message:

```
agent library failed to init: instrument

Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/newrelic-java-8.3.0.zip
```

Anyone had similar issue ?

version:

- spring-boot: 3.1

Also tried the following configuration with bindings but does not appear in the image:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why are you using maven-dependency-plugin? Buildpack etc. will handle all that ...

Comment: using it as a shortcut @khmarbaise

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why your approach isn't working, but you might have better luck letting the [Paketo Buildpack for New Relic](https://paketo.io/docs/howto/app-monitor/#new-relic) install and configure the agent for you. This buildpack is not included by default, so you'll need to configure your build to use it. You'll also need to create a binding to give the agent any configuration that it needs.

For the binding, create a `bindings` directory in the root of your project structure (at the same level as the project `src` directory) and create some files in that directory. The `type` file is required, any others depend on what you need to configure the agent:

```
$ mkdir -p bindings/newrelic
$ echo "NewRelic" > bindings/newrelic/type
$ echo "my-app-name" > bindings/newrelic/app-name
$ echo "licence key" > bindings/newrelic/license-key
$ tree bindings
bindings
├── newrelic
│   ├── type
│   └── app-name
│   └── license-key
```

Then configure the Spring Boot Maven plugin to add the New Relic buildpack and provide the binding:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <image>
        <buildpacks>
          <buildpack>urn:cnb:builder:paketo-buildpacks/java</buildpack>
          <buildpack>paketobuildpacks/new-relic</buildpack>
        </buildpacks>
        <bindings>
          <binding>${basedir}/bindings/newrelic:/platform/bindings/newrelic</binding>
        </bindings>
      </image>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

More information on configuring the Spring Boot Maven plugin is available in [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.customization).

Comment: thanks for taking the time to anwser scott! I updated my post using bindings, shouldn't the bindings dir appear in the image ?

Comment: No, the bindings won't appear in the generated image. They will be visible to the buildpacks running in the builder image. If things are working right, the New Relic agent, a yaml config file, and other files should be in a layer contributed by the NR buildpack based on the contents of the binding.

Comment: You should be able to see from the output of the `spring-boot:build-image` goal what buildpacks are being run and what they are doing. You can set `<verboseLogging>true</verboseLogging>` in the Spring Boot Maven plugin configuration to get more detailed logging from the buildpacks (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.customization).

Comment: actually made it work by putting the newrelic.yml inside the resource folder at "-Dnewrelic.config.file=/workspace/BOOT-INF/classes/newrelic.yml" but "-Dnewrelic.config.file=/platform/bindings/newrelic/newrelic.yml" was not found pretty strange. 

`The configuration file /platform/bindings/newrelic/newrelic.yml specified with the newrelic.config.file property does not exist`

Comment: That's to be expected. The `/platform/bindings` directory will exist in the image that the buildpacks run in, but it won't exist in the image that is generated by buildpacks. Bindings are used to configure buildpack behavior, not to contribute to the generated image. More info about that here: https://paketo.io/docs/howto/configuration/#bindings.

Comment: I would have expected that the New Relic buildpack would configure the agent without you needing to explicitly set `-Dnewrelic.config.file`. It seems to try to do that here: https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/new-relic/blob/main/newrelic/java_agent.go#L56-L57. But I'm not an expert on that specific Paketo buildpack. You can reach out to the Paketo team in the GitHub repo or on Slack: https://paketo.io/community/

Comment: Yes it does! But I configured my own this is why i needed to inject it!